# redis-server - What are the differences between rwky/redis and chris-lea/redis-server?

Tags: ppa, redis

What are the differences between https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/redis-server
and   https://launchpad.net/~rwky/+archive/ubuntu/redis?

Comment: I've no idea.  But I just read through https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1732 which makes me trust ppa:chris-lea/redis-server.  I know nothing about ppa:rwky/redis.

Comment: there actually isn't much of a difference however if your planning on building a nodejs app - i recommend chris-lea as their package always contains the latest stable version of redis-server.

Comment: Keep in mind that rwky is no longer maintained and that it is recommended to use the chris-lea ppa.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but considering it never received an answer:

https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/redis-server is a (somewhat) currently maintained launchpad build of redis while https://launchpad.net/~rwky/+archive/ubuntu/redis seems to be non-existent these days meaning it was probably someones fork to either fix their own bugs, or possible to do work and submit the changes back upstream.

~chris-lea seems to maintain many PPAs for different web related packages, without actually being associated with the packages development, which points to someone who probably for work or the like needs to make sure there is simple access to build-able code, hence the first P of PPA (Personal).

**TL;DR** - Use the first one - it works.

Comment: I think the TL;DR is supposed to be at the top *not* bottom  of document... but thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an official PPA at:

[https://launchpad.net/~redislabs/+archive/ubuntu/redis](https://launchpad.net/%7Eredislabs/+archive/ubuntu/redis)

This was made in colloboration with Chris Lea, so it seems antirez trusts him. So if the official ppa has no build, use chrislea. See the thread here: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/1732